# Vertical top align gloss with \gll from gb4e in tabular

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, linguistics, gb4e

I looked through the questions but couldn't find someone with the same problem.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a5paper]{book}

\usepackage{gb4e}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ r X }
\large{\textbf{1}} & \\ \hline
\small{\textbf{\textsf{EN}}} & The weather is nice today. \\[1ex]
\small{\textbf{\textsf{FR}}} & {\gll Il fait beau aujourd'hui. \\
                                    [il fɛ bo oʒuʁdɥi] \\}
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

This puts the french sentence and gloss too low, and I want it vertically aligned with the FR on the left.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This answer is a long time coming, but the solution is simple: there is a patched version of `cgloss4e` (which is the glossing macros part of `gb4e`) written by Alexis Dimitriadis, and available on his website (not on CTAN, unfortunately). It is called and can be used as a drop-in replacement. It also has some other niceties. You can get it [here](http://www.hum.uu.nl/medewerkers/a.dimitriadis/latex/cgloss.sty). I use it in all my documents.

Put it in your local `texmf` folder, and you load it after you load `gb4e`.  I've also added some code from the `array` package to increase your table spacing without having to manually use a space after your rows. (Compile with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX for the phonetics in the source.).

```
\documentclass[12pt,a5paper]{book}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{gb4e,cgloss}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}


\begin{document}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{1ex}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ r X }
\large{\textbf{1}} & \\ \hline
\small{\textbf{\textsf{EN}}} & The weather is nice today. \\
\small{\textbf{\textsf{FR}}} & {\gll Il fait beau aujourd'hui. \\
                                    [il fɛ bo oʒuʁdɥi] \\}\\
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]